# What defines the distribution of longest run of selective people in a group?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let's say we have a number of people $N$ lined up. Now, $M < N$ aliens join the line by taking over one of the humans. Obviously, an alien cannot take over the mind of another alien. By the end we have $N - M$ people lined up with $M$ aliens. What is the distribution of the longest sequence $L(N, M)$ of aliens that are standing next to each other?

Comment: I doubt there is a closed form, but you can probably do this by recursion or inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify the cdf of $L(N,M)$, denote by $a_{n,m}$ the number of lineups of $n$ humans and $m$ aliens with longest alien run not exceeding some fixed $k\ge 1$. Each such lineup (with at least one alien) has the following form.

- It starts with a (possibly, empty) sequence of people;
- then goes a non-empty sequence of aliens not exceeding $k$;
- then a (possibly, empty) sequence of such objects: a non-empty sequence of people followed by a non-empty sequence of aliens not longer than $k$;
- finally, a (possibly, empty) sequence of people.

So in the [symbolic language](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf), it is 
$$
\operatorname{Seq} (\mathcal{Z})\times \operatorname{Seq}_{1\text{ to }k} (\mathcal{U})\times \operatorname{Seq}\big(\operatorname{Seq}_{\ge 1} (\mathcal{Z})\times \operatorname{Seq}_{1\text{ to }k} (\mathcal{U})\big)\times \operatorname{Seq} (\mathcal{Z}),
$$
where $\mathcal Z$ and $\mathcal U$ are atomic classes containing single human and a single alien respectively. 
Theefore, the bivariate generating function of $a_{n,m}$ is 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{n,k} z^n u^m = \frac{1}{1-z}\frac{u-u^{k+1}}{1-u}\frac{1}{1- \frac{z}{1-z}\frac{u-u^{k+1}}{1-u}} \frac{1}{1-z} = \frac{u-u^{k+1}}{(1-z)\big(1-z-u + zu^{k+1}\big)}.
$$
From here it is possible to express $a_{n,m}$ as a multiple sum involving some binomial coefficients. Probably, one can get the same with the help of inclusion/exclusion.